# Node.js: Single variable, multiple promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to create multiple promises, and I really don't care about race in this code, as long as all callbacks are done.

So, I have a variable, which holds all data, let's say:

```
export interface IData {
    data1: string[],
    data2: string[],
    data3: string[]
}
```

Those 3 are unrelated, and I have a data fetcher.. say:

```
function getData(id: string): Promise<IData> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var data = new TableFetcher();
        data.get(_id)
        .then((result : IData) => {
            resolve()
        })
    })
}
```

Now, I want to make something like:

```
function x(): Promise<IData> {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        var data: IData = {
            data1: getData('100'),
            data2: getData('200'),
            data3: getData('300')
        }
        resolve(data)
    })
}
```

when all getData promises has finished.

It doesn't need to chain but all can be run separately, but I need to return an array containing all asynchronous data after they are done.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!
2. Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to make a promise for the results from an array of promises:

```
function getData(id: string): Promise<string[]> {
    return new TableFetcher().get(id);
}
function x(): Promise<IData> {
    return Promise.all([
        getData('100'),
        getData('200'),
        getData('300')
    ]).then(([data1, data2, data3]) => {
        return <IData>{data1, data2, data3};
    });
}
```

Comment: I saw `promise.all` construct, but I can't find `reject` there. How can I send `reject` to x()'s caller?

Comment: @Magician if any of the promises passed to Promise.all() is rejected, the resulting promise will also be rejected.

Comment: yes, I know it is rejected, but I need to pass error data to x() caller. something like X.then().catch(here=>console.log(here));

Comment: @Magician Yes, exactly like that. Any error from one of the `getData(…)` promises will reject the returned promise and can be caught with `x().….catch(err => …)`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function x(): Promise<IData> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Promise.all([getData('100'), getData('200'), getData('300')])
            .then(result => {
                var data: IData = {
                    data1: result[0],
                    data2: result[1],
                    data3: result[2]
                }
                resolve(data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(err)
            })

    })
}
```